# How to encode FNC1 starting character to make GS1 Datamatrix?

Tags: datamatrix, gs1-datamatrix

I have made string for GS1 Datamatrix

è010506060985000521sn1234567890ab 1002TRIAL003 17200228

- ASCII 232
- (01) Product Code (aka GTIN)
- (21) Serial Number
- ASCII 29 (aka  aka Group Separator)
- (10) Lot/Batch
- ASCII 29 (aka  aka Group Separator)
- (17) Expiry Date

I am passing this string to Dev express Control – symbology as Datamatrix and compatible mode as ASCII.

This barcode scan correctly [click here to view barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIQGN.png) as GS1 Datamatrix, but when I sent this string to our printing person in China, he did printed but when I am scanning his barcode getting error “Unknown encoding”.

I thing their system is not able to encode ASCII 232 – “è”.

**Is any alternate way?**

I am just replacing FNC 1 Start changer ASCII 232 to ASCII 29, is it correct way? [click here to view barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SNQf.png) **Is it GS1 Datamatrix?**

(I just scan that in one mobile app in that it comes as GS1 Datamatrix but when did I scan into another app it just come as Datamatrix)

I want to achieve GS1 Datamatrix...

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

this issue is totally dependant on the hardware used. The way to indicate FNC1 character may differ between printer family/type. Do you have info on which one is used in your case?

First, your printer partner should check himself the label he's creating (there is a GS1 app easy to use on smartphone to do that), so he can directly see if the expected information are present and well encoded.

Then, you should check which printer type he is using and which software is used to create the printer mask/job. I know lots of people are using NiceLabel for example, but I remember some issues can be found on the FNC1 character is you are using some recent Zebra printer for example. This is something the printer SAV can probably help with if it's something similar.

[EDIT]:In case of doubt [this](https://www.gs1.org/docs/barcodes/GS1_DataMatrix_Guideline.pdf) can help but you probably have it already. 
Based on what you said, your part is acting like a scanner, so check chapter 2.2.1 => Important: In accordance with ISO/IEC 15424 - Data Carrier Identifiers (including
Symbology Identifiers), the Symbology Identifier is the first three characters transmitted by
the scanner indicating symbology type. For a GS1 DataMatrix the symbology identifier is ]d2